# How to share an Ubuntu guest VPN connection to a Windows host

Tags: vpn

I use a VMware virtual machine to install the Ubuntu system, and then run Windscribe inside to establish a VPN connection, but I want to share this VPN connection to the Windows10 host, what should I do? Thanks!